What is wrong in the following derivation using confluent hypergeometric function integral representations?
Edit:
I managed to find the integral representations to solve the integral, but I am getting the wrong answer. So, I must be doing something wrong. It is probably a silly mistake. The steps
are as follows:

Start from the Gaussian integral and expand to get the integral in the first link

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{x \cdot \mu}{\|x\| \|\mu\|}\right] &=
\frac{1}{(2\pi \sigma^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}
e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x-\mu)^T(x-\mu)} \frac{x \cdot \mu}{\|x\| \|\mu\|} dx = \nonumber \\
    &\quad \frac{1}{(2\pi \sigma^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}}  e^{-\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}}
\int_{0}^{\infty} dr \int_{0}^{\pi } r \mathrm{A}_{n-2}(r\sin(\theta))
e^{-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}} e^{\frac{r\|\mu\|}{\sigma^2}\cos(\theta)} 
\cos(\theta) d\theta
\end{align}
where $\mathrm{A}_{n-2}(r\sin(\theta)) = \frac{2\pi^{(n-1)/2}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}\,r^{n-2} \sin^{n-2}(\theta)$ is the area of the $n-2$ sphere of radius $r\sin(\theta)$.

Use the subtitution and integral representation suggested in the answer by Roland. Substituting $\cos(\theta)=z$,
$\sin^{n-2}(\theta)=(1-z^2)^{\frac{n-2}{2}}$ and
$d\theta = -(1-z^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}} dz$

\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{-1} - z e^{\left(\frac{r\|\mu\|}{\sigma^2}\right)z}
    (1-z^2)^{\frac{n-2}{2}-\frac{1}{2}} dz  = \\
 \quad \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \Gamma\left( \frac{n-1}{2} \right) \frac{\|\mu\| r}{\sigma^2}
    {}_0F_1\left(;\frac{n}{2}+1; \left( \frac{\|\mu\| r}{2\sigma^2}\right)^2 \right)
\end{align}

Get all terms that don't depend on $r$ outside of the integral, and simplify.

\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{(2\sigma^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}} e^{-\frac{\|\mu\|^2}{2\sigma^2}}
\frac{\|\mu\|}{\sigma^2}
\int_{0}^{\infty} r^n e^{-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}}
{}_0F_1\left(;\frac{n}{2}+1; \left( \frac{\|\mu\| r}{2\sigma^2}\right)^2 \right) dr
\end{align}

Substitute $z=\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}$, which implies $r^n=2^{n/2}z^{n/2}\sigma^n$, and $dr=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2z}}dz$ and simplify

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(2\sigma^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}} e^{-\frac{\|\mu\|^2}{2\sigma^2}} \|\mu\|
    \int_{0}^{\infty} z^{\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2}} e^{-z}
    {}_0F_1\left(;\frac{n}{2}+1; \frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}z \right) dz
\end{align}

Use the integral representation ${}_1F_1(a;b;z)\Gamma(a) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} t^{a-1} {}_0F_1\left(;b;zt\right)dt$ to evaluate the integral

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(2\sigma^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}} e^{-\frac{\|\mu\|^2}{2\sigma^2}}
    \|\mu\| \Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2} \right)
    {}_1F_1\left(\frac{n+1}{2}; \frac{n}{2}+1; \frac{\|\mu\|^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
\end{equation}

Use Kummer's transformation to get rid of the $e^{-\frac{\|\mu\|^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ term

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(2\sigma^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}
    \|\mu\| \Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2} \right)
    {}_1F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}; \frac{n}{2}+1; -\frac{\|\mu\|^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
\end{equation}
However, this is different from the correct answer below, which is given in the original link:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{x}{\|x\|}\right] = \frac{1}{(2\sigma^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}
    \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2} \right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1 \right)}
    {}_1F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}; \frac{n}{2}+1; -\frac{\|\mu\|^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \mu
\end{equation}
which implies
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{x \cdot \mu}{\|x\| \|\mu\|}\right] = \frac{1}{(2\sigma^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}
    \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2} \right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1 \right)} \|\mu\|
    {}_1F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}; \frac{n}{2}+1; -\frac{\|\mu\|^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
\end{equation}
Thus, I am missing a $\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}$ factor, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I'd really appreciate help spotting the error.
My guess is that the problem is in step 2. I think that the integral representation may be missing some $\Gamma$ factor. I suppose that the answer below used some trigonometric identity to be able to use some representation from this list, but I can't tell what it is.

Original question:
In this answer, someone provided the following closed form equation for the expectation of a projected normal distribution:
$$
\mathbb E\left( \frac{X}{||X||}\right) = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{(2\sigma^2)^{1/2}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}{}_1F_1\left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{n+2}{2};-\frac{|\mu|^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\,\mu,\tag{$\ast$}
$$
where $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2 I)$ and ${}_1F_1(a;b;z)$ is Kummer's confluent hypergeometric function. Simulations show the formula to work.
As an intermediate step, they provided the following integral for the expectation:
$$
\mathbb E\left( \frac{\mu\cdot X}{||\mu||X||}\right) =(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-n/2}e^{-\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}}\int_0^\infty dr\int_0^\pi d\theta \,r\,A_{n-2}(r\sin\theta)e^{-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}+\frac{\mu r}{\sigma^2}\cos\theta}\frac{\cos\theta}{r},
$$
where $A_{n-1}(r)=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}r^{n-1}$ is the area of a $(n-1)$-sphere of radius $r$. However, the jump from the integral to the final formula is obscure to me.
I understand that it will involve some integral representation of ${}_1F_1(a;b;z)$. I looked at lists of such integral representations (e.g. here, or textbooks) but I can't figure out how to connect this integral to the closed-form formula.
Being a non-mathematician (I'm a biologist), I try to find integral representations that somewhat fit that form as a starting point, but most that I find are either integrals from 0 to 1, or which include Bessel functions of the second kind (like in the link above), which I don't know how to relate to this formula. I also tried starting from other integral expressions for the expectation, such as the one in this other answer to the same question, to no avail.
I would be grateful if someone knowledgeable on these topics could provide some insight into what steps take us from the expected value integral of this variable to the closed-form formula with the confluent hypergeometric function.

I think I can show you another way to prove the following claim :
Claim :
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X}{\|X\|}\right)=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}{(2\sigma^2)^{1/2}\Gamma(\frac{n+2}{2})}{}_1F_1\bigg(\frac{1}{2};\frac{n+2}{2};-\frac{\|\mu\|^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigg)\mu$$
Proof :
Using River Li's answer, we have
$$\begin{align}
 \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X}{\|X\|}\right) 
 &= \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X}{(\|X\|^2)^{1/2}}\right)
\\\\&=\mathbb{E}\left(X \cdot \frac{1}{\Gamma(1/2)}\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-z\|X\|^2}z^{-1/2}\,dz \right)
\\\\&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty \mathbb{E}\left(X\mathrm{e}^{-z\|X\|^2}\right)z^{-1/2}\,dz
\\\\&= \mu \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\frac{\|\mu\|^2 z}{2\sigma^2 z + 1}} \cdot z^{-1/2}}{(2\sigma^2 z + 1)^{(n+2)/2}}dz\end{align}$$
Letting $t=\frac{1}{2\sigma^2 z + 1}$, we have $\frac{dt}{dz}=-2\sigma^2 t^2$, so we obtain
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X}{\|X\|}\right)=\mu\cdot \frac{e^{-\frac{\|\mu\|^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{(2\sigma^2)^{1/2} \sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^1 e^{\frac{\|\mu\|^2t}{2\sigma^2}}t^{\frac{n-1}2}(1-t)^{-1/2}dt$$
According to here, we can say that if $\text{Re}(b)\gt \text{Re}(a)\gt 0$, then we have
$$\int_0^1e^{zt}t^{a-1}(1-t)^{-a+b-1}dt=\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b-a)\ _{1}\bar{F}_1(a;b;z)$$
So, taking $a=\frac{n+1}{2},b=\frac{n+2}{2}$ and $z=\frac{\|\mu\|^2}{2\sigma^2}$, we have
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X}{\|X\|}\right)=\mu\cdot\frac{e^{-\frac{\|\mu\|^2}{2\sigma^2}}\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}{(2\sigma^2)^{1/2}}{}_1\bar{F}_1\bigg(\frac{n+1}{2};\frac{n+2}{2};\frac{\|\mu\|^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigg)$$
Since $_{1}\bar{F}_{1}(a;b;z)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(b)}\ _{1}F_{1}(a;b;z)$, we have
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X}{\|X\|}\right)= \mu\cdot\frac{e^{-\frac{\|\mu\|^2}{2\sigma^2}}\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}{(2\sigma^2)^{1/2}\Gamma(\frac{n+2}{2})}{}_1F_1\bigg(\frac{n+1}{2},\frac{n+2}{2};\frac{\|\mu\|^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigg)$$
Since $_{1}F_1(a;b;z)=e^z\ _{1}F_1(b-a;b;-z)$, we finally get
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X}{\|X\|}\right)=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2})}{(2\sigma^2)^{1/2}\Gamma(\frac{n+2}{2})}{}_1F_1\bigg(\frac{1}{2};\frac{n+2}{2};-\frac{\|\mu\|^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigg)\mu.\ \blacksquare$$

Added :
There is an error in step 2 since it is wrong that
$$\int_{1}^{-1} z \left(-e^{a z}\right) \left(1-z^2\right)^{\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2}} dz = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi }\ a\ \Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)  {}_0F_1\left(\frac{n}{2}+2;\frac{a^2}{4}\right)$$
According to WolframAlpha, for $(a,n)=(2,1)$, we have
$$LHS=\frac{e^4+3}{4e^2}\not=\frac{3\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\times\frac{e^4+3}{4e^2}=RHS$$
My conjecture is
$$\int_{1}^{-1} z \left(-e^{a z}\right) \left(1-z^2\right)^{\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2}} dz = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}\ a\ \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{\color{red}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+4}{2}\right)}}\ {}_0F_1\left(\frac{n}{2}+2;\frac{a^2}{4}\right)\tag1$$
According to WolframAlpha, for small $n$, $(1)$ holds.
However, I don't know how to prove that the conjecture is true.

Thanks, I'll check it out and if I it pans out I'll give you the bounty. I'm curious though, did you try to find the missing 1/Gamma factor in the question?

@dherrera : Yes. See Added in the answer.

I think I figured it out. If you give Wolfram alpha the integral in step 2 it will seemingly give you the answer in step 2. But it mentions the regularized 0F1, which I think means it's missing a gamma factor like you propose

The essential step is to isolate the $\theta$-dependent term, substitute $ \cos \theta = z,\ d\theta=-\frac{dz}{\sqrt(1-z^2)} $ such that a relatively simple integral results
$$d\theta  \cos (\theta ) e^{a \cos (\theta )} \sin ^n(\theta )\text{/.}\, \left\{\cos (\theta )\to z,\sin ^n(\theta )\to \left(1-z^2\right)^{n/2},d\theta \to -\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\right\}  = z \left(-e^{a z}\right) \left(1-z^2\right)^{\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2}} dz$$
$$\int_{1}^{-1} z \left(-e^{a z}\right) \left(1-z^2\right)^{\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2}} \, dz = \frac{1}{2} \ \sqrt{\pi }\  a \ \Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) \, _0F_1\left(\frac{n}{2}+2;\frac{a^2}{4}\right)$$
with $a=\frac{\mu r}{\sigma^2}$
Together with the rest of r-dependent terms one has to do the r-integral.

Thanks for the help. Still, as you say, we still have to do the r-integral, for which I would still be lacking the relevant integral representation of 1F1 that leads me to the final formula

I used your suggested approach and took it all the way but I'm missing a factor in the answer. I can't find some reference for your integral representation to double check whether your formula is what's missing the factor. Could you check my edit?

As mentioned in other comments, it seems like you missed a 1/Gamma(n/2 + 2) factor. That's what Mathematica says. It would be great if you could provide some reference for the integral representation, since I can't find this other than with Mathematica.
